# Adding credentials to curl -X GET http://instance_path:5984/somedb/_all_docs for couchdb. Currently says unauthorized

Tags: curl, couchdb

adding it in the form

> username:password@instancepath:5984/somedb

also doesn't work and gives 401: unauthorized error. How exactly do we pass the credentials for it to read.

Comment: `user:password@path:5984` is correct. If that doesn't work, you've probably provided improper credentials.

Comment: Try `-u username:password` instead, but it should do the same thing. Also, use verbose mode, and consider dumping headers to see if you're being redirected or something.